# Custom JS chart similat to a vertical progress bar

Tags: javascript, charts

I am searching for a JS chart like in the image. I got it from an excel file. The percentage is incorect, it should be from 0 to 100%. Does anyone know a library which provides this kind of chart ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for a bullet chart. Most of the major charting libraries provide bullet charts as a standard chart type. You could also implement it as a column (vertical bar) chart with some additional styling.

Here is a [ZingChart demo of a vertical bullet chart](http://demos.zingchart.com/view/X7TZAY2V) with an area marker and here is a [similar demo implemented as a mixed chart](http://demos.zingchart.com/view/UFZ6CN8U) - a column chart and a scatter plot marker for the "goal" line. Both replicate your image.

I'm on the ZingChart team, so don't hesitate to reach out if you have any questions!